# What happened to my account on Physics Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, suspensions

Today when I clicked on Physics.Stackexchange tab on my chrome the site opened up normally but when I clicked on **Ask** the window the tab opened up saying “confirm your account” and then I saw that my account from P.SE was removed or something like that must have happened. 
I was suspended from asking questions (I think in month of July or something) because my questions were homework-like and always received downvotes so SE told me that I will be able to ask again after six months, are these two events related in any way?

My account on all other SE is as it was only on PSE this has happened.

Thank you! Any clarification will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's strange. There are [no search results for 'confirm your account' on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22confirm+your+account%22). Was that the precise wording on the page? Do you have a screenshot? This is probably worth it for you to directly contact the SE team (link at bottom left on the desktop version) just to confirm everything is OK.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sounds a lot like the screen you get when you haven't joined a particular community but you're signed into the SE network (or at least I get a similar message when signed in through my google account and I go to join a new SE site).

Comment: @JMac Ah, yes, that's probably what it is. Adesh, is [this](//i.stack.imgur.com/jrrUt.png) the screen you're referring to? If so, are you sure that you had a previous account on the physics site? Your profile page lists your account as being created today.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes. That's exactly how it came.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjjmsvI-qPnAhUUXisKHbVkDbIQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fphysics.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F444237%2Fquestion-on-force-between-dipoles&usg=AOvVaw3jh63v0rt-uz_doDySrK-S) question was asked by me and AaronStevens answered it but now it is removed.

Comment: Aw. Poor answer

Answer (score 3):

This occurred because your account was deleted on Physics.SE.

If you believe this action is in error and you have not received a message from the moderators or the staff, use the Contact form to contact SE directly.